# What is the purpose of the column with the '0' after the numeric timestamp in .zsh_history?

Tags: zsh, command-history, columns

What is the purpose of the column with `0` after the numeric timestamp in .zsh_history?

```
: 1568128379:0;cp -a ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc
: 1568128381:0;exit
```

Is it part of the timestamp or does it serve a different purpose altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the shell's `EXTENDED_HISTORY` option is *set*, then this number is the elapsed number of second that the command took to execute.

From the `zsh` manual (`info zsh extended_history` or the `zshoptions(1)` man page):

> `EXTENDED_HISTORY` `<C>`
> Save each command's beginning timestamp (in seconds since the
> epoch) and the duration (in seconds) to the history file.  The
> format of this prefixed data is:
>
> `: <beginning time>:<elapsed seconds>;<command>`

This number is also displayed, in human readable "MM:SS" format, when you use the `history` built-in with its `-D` option.

Example showing `sleep 7` taking 7 seconds:

```bash
% sleep 7
% tail -n 2 $HISTFILE
: 1697802061:7;sleep 7
: 1697802074:0;tail -n 2 $HISTFILE
```

```bash
% history -D -2
 3158  0:07  sleep 7
 3159  0:00  tail -n 2 $HISTFILE
```

Example showing I ran `mutt` for 3008 seconds (50 minutes and 8 seconds) at some point:

```bash
% history -D 2070 2070
 2070  50:08  mutt
% sed '2070!d' $HISTFILE
: 1697438226:3008;mutt
```

As to why it may be showing as `0` for you, see [Why is the duration column in .zsh_history usually 0, although the "history -D" command displays it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/760046)