# Why is the duration column in .zsh_history usually 0, although the "history -D" command displays it?

Tags: zsh, command-history

Why is the duration column in .zsh_history usually 0, although the "history -D" command displays it?

After testing [this answer](/a/759425) to [What is the purpose of the column with the '0' after the numeric timestamp in .zsh_history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/759424) I notice that although the `history -D` command displays the running time of the command, the duration column in `~/.zsh_history` still displays `0`.

What is the cause of this?

Is it because the `~/.zsh_history` file is updated on the initial command and not updated after, or the `history -D` obtains the time from a separate location, perhaps from memory or another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same question after answering your previous question when I looked at my own setup.  When answering your earlier question, I was using a `zsh` shell session with the default settings, and I looked at the history file after enabling `EXTENDED_HISTORY`. I could see the duration being properly written after the termination of the shell session (which is when the in-memory history is written to the `$HISTFILE` file by default).  In my own `$HISTFILE` file, however, I noticed that the durations were all zero, even though I used `EXTENDED_HISTORY`.

After inquiring with the `zsh-users` mailing list, it turns out that since I also use the `SHARE_HISTORY` shell option (to share the same command history between multiple concurrent shell sessions), the duration is not written to the history file.  This is because the `SHARE_HISTORY` option causes the history event to be written upon *execution* of the command rather than at the *termination* of the command or of the shell session, when the duration is available.  This behaviour is similar to enabling `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` but also reads new commands into the current shell's history from the other sessions.

However, there is another shell option, `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME` (note the trailing `_TIME`), which is *incompatible* with `SHARE_HISTORY` and `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`, which appends the history events to the file in the way that we expect, after the termination of a command.

The `zshoptions(1)` manual says this:

> `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME`
> This option is a variant of `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` in which, where
> possible, the history entry is written out to the file after the
> command is finished, so that the time taken by the command is
> recorded correctly in the history file in `EXTENDED_HISTORY`
> format.  This means that the history entry will not be available
> immediately from other instances of the shell that are using the
> same history file.
>
> This option is only useful if `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` and
> `SHARE_HISTORY` are turned off.  The three options should be
> considered mutually exclusive.

If you want to use `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME` and still be able to share the history between several concurrent shell sessions, the documentation for the `SHARE_HISTORY` option suggests using `fc -RI` in a shell to read the events from the other shells when these are needed:

> If you find that you want more control over when commands get
> imported, you may wish to turn `SHARE_HISTORY` off,
> `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` or `INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME` (see above) on,
> and then manually import commands whenever you need them using
> `fc -RI`.

The difference between the output of `history -D` and the contents of `$HISTFILE` is due to the former showing the in-memory history events and the latter containing the history events written to the history file.  What is written to the history file (and when) is dependent on various shell options, which, by this point (after the above exposition), is hopefully evident.